# Use controller method in all controllers sitewide

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I'm starting to use cakephp as a new framework, and its a very awesome one.
My problem now is that I need to keep track of user accessed views and store what they accessed, the time, the page id on the database and when they leave the view.

I don't want to relate all controllers to this controller because I will have a long list of relations.
i want to use it when the page is loaded, get the information I need and store it.

On php traditional I make an inclusion of a file with the logic that store the user access to the page. I would like to know the best or recommended way to do this task.

Comment: maybe this is what you want http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html

Comment: sounds like you want google analytics especially because of `when they leave the view`. Otherwise you want to put code in your AppController::afterFilter - probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your method in the AppController's beforeFilter, beforeRender, afterFilter etc methods. As long as you inherit your Controller Classes from your AppController the method is available application wide.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and be back with the results.